# Can we use the word "actually" over phone for a business call?

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I use of word **actually** in the following scenarios for a business call.

1) **Actually** we are calling from so and so company.

2) We **actually** develop mobile applications for business. Do you wish to have one?

Does it sound professional?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a question of professionalism. "Actually" means "as a matter of fact" (in British English especially), so unless there is some special context, both your sentences are invalid.

Comment: Actually (!) both these sentences come across to me as Indian English.

Comment: @TonyK   :I used the first sentence when customer  wanted to know what was the purpose of my call.

Comment: @Gt_R: In that case, it is not so bad. But it still sounds strange. Specifically, the fact that you are from so and so company is not the _purpose_ of your call. Your example would rather serve as a response to "Why are you calling? Are you from whatsitsname company?"

Comment: @TonyK  :  **This was the scenario.**  He said he was busy and not interested to have a long conversation. So he was expecting me to come to the point rather than formalities. In order to make him clear that I am calling from a software company and my intention is to sell him a mobile application I used the above sentences.

Comment: @Gt_R: Then it sounds like you are using it correctly.

Comment: @Colin Fine :  Please see my comment above. What is your opinion on that?

Comment: @Gt_R - My opinion is that you should put critical information like that **in your question**, not in some comment below an answer. Whether or not the word "actually" sounds professional or superfluous depends on the rest of the conversation. [Details, Please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/).

Answer (score 1):

The word "actually" can be used in several places and it is purely context based.
Though the sentences cited in the question are grammatically proper and correct, 'actually' seems unnecessary rather.

Some definitions and examples where 'actually' could be used taken from Google:

Adverb

1.as the truth or facts of a situation.
"we must pay attention to what young people are actually doing"

2.used to emphasize that something someone has said or done is surprising.
"he actually expected me to be pleased about it!"

-used when expressing a contradictory or unexpected opinion or correcting someone.
"‘Tom's happy anyway.’ ‘He isn't, actually, not any more.’"

-used to introduce a new topic or to add information to a previous statement.
"he had a thick Cockney accent—he sounded like my grandad actually"

The sentences could be as follows:

1) We are calling from so and so company. (If the first statement the caller speaks was this)

2) We develop mobile applications for business. Do you wish to have one? (If the caller goes on without any questions/interruptions from the other end)

Again, if the situation prompts it, 'actually' could work there.
If the person on the other end asked what is the intention the call, the caller can go on like, "we called 'actually' for so and so purpose" .

Thanks.